# ¿Cómo mantener los comentarios publicados en la página?

Tags: php, mysql, php5

¿Qué puedo hacer para que los comentarios se queden en la página y por lo tanto sean públicos y visibles para cualquier usuario que llegue a mi página?

```
<form method="get" action="conexion.php">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <textarea rows="5" cols="5" name="commento"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>

<?php
$conexion = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'admin');
mysql_select_db('test', $conexion);

$query = "SELECT * FROM commenti";
while($fila = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $fila['nome'];
    echo $fila['commento'];
    echo $fila['fecha'];
}
?>
```

El error es el siguiente:

> mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, `mysql*` fue declarada obsoleta en `PHP 5.5.0` y eliminada en `PHP 7.0.0.` En su lugar debería utilizarse las extensiones `MySQLi` o `PDO_MySQL`.

También tener en cuenta, para [evitar la inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php), te aconsejo el uso de sentencias [mysqli::prepare](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php)

**Ejemplo MySQLi (Estilo por procedimientos):**

```
//Conexión.
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "admin", "test");

/* comprobar la conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$name = $_GET['name'];
$commento = $_GET['commento'];
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
$fecha= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$sql = "INSERT INTO commenti (nome, commento, fecha) VALUES ('$name', '$commento', '$fecha')" ;
$query = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
//Caso, si fallara nuestra sentencia.
if (!$query) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conexion));
}

echo $name;
echo $commento;
echo $fecha;
```

A tu respuesta, como obtener los comentarios para su publicación, lo podrías hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
//Conexión.
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "admin", "test");

/* comprobar la conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//Sentencia.
$sql = "SELECT nome,commento,fecha FROM commenti ORDER BY fecha DESC";
//Ejecutar sentencia.
$query = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

//Comprobamos existencia de registros.
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0) {
   //Obtenemos datos desde BD.
   while($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
     //Mostramos datos comentarios.
     echo $row['nome'];
     echo $row['commento'];
     //etc..
   }
} else {
   echo'0 comentarios encontrados en el sistema.';
}
```

En caso de querer mostrar unas cantidades, podrías utilizar `LIMIT`

```
$sql = "SELECT nome,commento,fecha FROM commenti ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: la verda que no entiendo lo que trae de nuevo la nueva version de php, lamento que no soporte algunas funciones, de todos modos seguire usando php5 y mysql hasta la ultima. respecto a tu solucion creo que dejar un while activo pondria lento la navegacion

Comment: @steven Dependerá de los registros (comentarios) que vayas a mostrar, siempre podrás utilizar la función `LIMIT` y mostrar una sola cantidad, así no mostrarías 40.000 si uno tendría tantos registros en la `Base de datos` o crear una paginación de `PHP` que sería lo ideal en ese caso. El enlace que te deje sobre cómo *evitar la inyección SQL*, te explica bien, porque no usar `mysql`, simplemente ahora mismo tu código es vulnerable. ¡Espero verte ayudado, un saludo!

Comment: interesante, nunca escuche hablar de esa funcion, no tengo miedo a injeccciones sql porque los datos de mi registro pueden ser cifrados y si en caso el quaker llegara a entrar, encontraria contenido cifrado, ademas para que pueden querer un sitio de pocas visitas

Comment: Podría quedar así `$sql = "SELECT nome,commento,fecha FROM commenti ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT 10";` de esta manera solo te va mostrar los últimos 10 registros, he puesto 10 como si quieres poner 1 o 2 o 3, ya depende la cantidad que deseas mostrar. Respecto a la inyección SQL, es un consejo, piensa que siempre hay personas aburridas en la vida, que no miren si una web tenga o no importancia o visitas, simplemente por entrenamiento, podrán manipular fácilmente tu Base de datos y eliminar toda tu `Base de datos`.

Comment: muchas gracias por el consejo lo tomare en cuenta, todavia no entiendo bien la diferencia entre mysqli y pdo, ambos sirven para evitar este tipo de ataques?

Comment: Tanto `mysqli_prepare` como `PDO` son más seguros ante la `inyección SQL`, la gran diferencia, es que con `PDO` te permite trabajar con todo tipo de bases de datos de la misma forma y `MySQLi` solo permite `MySQL`.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58423/discussion-between-steven-and-d-bulten).